# Problemas al escribir fichero txt usando BufferedWriter

Tags: java, android, archivo

Tengo un problema al escribir un fichero txt en android, al parecer a la hora de escribir en el fichero no se escribe nada, ya que el peso del fichero es de 0 bytes

Los atributos estáticos son los siguientes:

```
static String direccion = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Food.txt";
```

y este es el método que escribe:

```
//This method write Food in the file fich
public static String writeFile(Food f){

    String linea = "";
    try {
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(direccion, true));
        linea += f.getNombre()+";";
        linea += f.getFechaCompra()+";";
        linea += f.getFechaCaducidad();

        br.write(linea);
        Log.d("Ficheros","writeFile: " + linea);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return linea;
}
```

tengo un log.d que me muestra que la linea si tiene los datos que le estoy pasando del objeto food, es un método string ya que retorno los datos que e pasado a traves de un toast.

El siguiente código pertenece a la clase desde la que llamo al método

```
    add = findViewById(R.id.button);
    dateb = findViewById(R.id.datebuyadd);
    datee = findViewById(R.id.dateexpiryadd);
    foodn = findViewById(R.id.foodnameadd);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Food f = new Food(foodn.getText().toString(),dateb.getText().toString(), datee.getText().toString());
            MethodsFile.writeFile(f);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.foodaddlist),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Dejo tambien el fichero de lectura aunque creo que el problema no reside en el ya que e entrado al fichero que me crea la app y no hay nada escrito

```
public static ArrayList<Food> readFile(){

    Food f;
    ArrayList<Food> listFood = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader br;

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(direccion));
        String linea;

        while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
            f = new Food();
            String[] campos = linea.split(";");
            f.setNombre(campos[0]);
            f.setFechaCompra(campos[1]);
            f.setFechaCaducidad(campos[2]);
            Log.d("readFile", "Food: " + f.getNombre() + " Date b: "+ f.getFechaCompra() + " Date E: " + f.getFechaCaducidad());
            listFood.add(f);
        }
        Log.d("readFile", "Size" + listFood.size());

        br.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){

    }

    return listFood;

}
```

Tambien tengo logs realizados para ver si me esta leyendo las lineas, aunque en el caso del log readfile food no aparece nada directamente, y el segundo log me esta diciendo que la longitud del arraylist es de 0

Los metodos están puestos en el manifest y tambien se los pido de forma manual al usuario.

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer y escribir!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al escribir en el archivo, tienes que cerrarlo mediante el método [BufferedWriter.close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close--) para guardar los datos, esto para cerrar el stream y evitar perdida de información.

ejemplo:

```
public static String writeFile(Food f){

    String linea = "";
    try {
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(direccion, true));
        linea += f.getNombre()+";";
        linea += f.getFechaCompra()+";";
        linea += f.getFechaCaducidad();

        br.write(linea);
        Log.d("Ficheros","writeFile: " + linea);

        //*Cierra stream.
        br.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return linea;
}
```

Comment: Cierto que fallo tan estupido, no me di cuenta